# Wordpress code breaks on database query

Tags: database, wordpress, hook, action

```
add_action( 'trash_post', 'producers_xml' );

function producers_xml($post_id){
    if($post_id){
        $post_type = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT element_type FROM wp_icl_translations WHERE element_id = '".$post_id."'");

        if($post_type[0]->element_type == 'post_producer'){
            die("Yes");

        }
    }
```

}

Testing this code locally (and substituting the $post_id with a hard-coded value) is no problem, but when I place it in this function, it breaks right before the database query. I've checked the $post_id and it is set and holds the value I want to search. But anything after that query doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you global $wpdb first

```
global $wpdb;  
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT element_type FROM wp_icl_translations WHERE element_id = %d", $post_id) );
//dump the results to see what we get back
var_dump($results); 
die();
```